# Get all (non repeated) distribuidores with their paises given a producto_solicitud

Tags: postgresql, join

I have this schema:

[image]

And as title says I need to get all records from `fabricante_distribuidor` by given `producto_solicitud.id` value. I'm doing in this way:

```
SELECT
    nomencladores.fabricante_distribuidor.*,
  nomencladores.pais.*
FROM
    nomencladores.fabricante_distribuidor,
    nomencladores.pais
LEFT JOIN negocio.distribuidor_producto_solicitud ON (
    negocio.distribuidor_producto_solicitud.fabricante_distribuidor_id = nomencladores.fabricante_distribuidor. ID
)
LEFT JOIN nomencladores.pais_distribuidor_producto_solicitud ON (
    negocio.distribuidor_producto_solicitud. ID = nomencladores.pais_distribuidor_producto_solicitud.distribuidor_producto_solicitud_id
)
WHERE
    negocio.distribuidor_producto_solicitud.producto_solicitud_id = 1
```

But get this error:

> ```
> [Err] ERROR:  invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "fabricante_distribuidor"
> LINE 8:> ...r_producto_solicitud.fabricante_distribuidor_id = nomenclado...
>                                  ^
> HINT:  There is an entry for table "fabricante_distribuidor", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.
> ```

I've tried also this one:

```
SELECT
    nomencladores.fabricante_distribuidor.*
FROM
    nomencladores.fabricante_distribuidor
JOIN negocio.distribuidor_producto_solicitud ON (
    negocio.distribuidor_producto_solicitud.fabricante_distribuidor_id = nomencladores.fabricante_distribuidor. ID
)
JOIN nomencladores.pais_distribuidor_producto_solicitud ON (
    negocio.distribuidor_producto_solicitud. ID = nomencladores.pais_distribuidor_producto_solicitud.distribuidor_producto_solicitud_id
)
WHERE
    negocio.distribuidor_producto_solicitud.producto_solicitud_id = 1
```

But this one return repeated results, any help?

I'm using PostgreSQL but assume that will be pretty much closed to any SQL statement.

Comment: Your requirements are unclear. Do you want 1 row per combination of `(fabricante, pais)` (which will feature each fabricante 0-n times), or one row per `(fabricante)` (and an array of all related paises)? And do you want fabricantes in the result that are not linked to *any* paises?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2nd query:
Of course you get duplicate rows. 1 row per `producto` each `fabricante` is connected to - multiplied with the number of rows in `pais` each combination is connected to.

1st query:
An explicit JOIN binds before (groups of) comma-separated items in the `FROM` list. This is why you cannot reference `fabricante` in the `JOIN` condition between `pais` and `distribuidor_producto_solicitud` - that happens *before* the result of this operation is joined to `fabricante`. [Per documentation:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM)

> In the absence of parentheses, `JOIN`s nest left-to-right. In any case
>   **`JOIN` binds more tightly than the commas** separating `FROM`-list items.

Bold emphasis mine.

The unconditional `CROSS JOIN` (comma-notation) between `fabricante` and the rest is a mistake to begin with. You probably want:

```
SELECT DISTINCT f.*, p.*
FROM   negocio.distribuidor_producto_solicitud d
JOIN   nomencladores.fabricante_distribuidor   f ON f.id = d.fabricante_distribuidor_id
LEFT   JOIN nomencladores.pais_distribuidor_producto_solicitud pd
                                                 ON pd.distribuidor_producto_solicitud_id = d.id
JOIN   nomencladores.pais                      p ON p.id = pd.pais.id
WHERE  d.producto_solicitud_id = 1;
```

Gives you one row for every combination of `(fabricante, pais)`. The `LEFT JOIN` is there to include fabricantes that have *no* pais attached.

You need the `DISTINCT`, because there can be any numbers of rows in `distributor` for each `fabricante`.

With your verbose naming convention I suggest to use table aliases to make the query more readable.

Answer (score 0):

In the second query you ommited **nomencladores.pais.*** in the select and as there can be several **pais_id** for each **distribuidor_producto_solicitud.producto_solicitud_id** it is very likely that you are getting repeated results for this reason.

However, if the only problem is that you are getting repeated results the only thing you need is to add the keyword DISTINCT in the select. http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-select-distinct/